# force default version of google appengine to update on deployment

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Java based web application running on google appengine that depends on data in the datastore. When I update this backend data and deploy. I can see the data change immediately if I access the url 1-dot-myapp.appspot.com. I cannot get the default version of the url (myapp.appspot.com) to update on another device unless I access the full specific version of the url.

How can I force the default version of the application to update on deployment?

Thank you

Comment: Doesn't sound expected. Heard of some cookies that may cause something similar. I know it sounds silly, but you've cleared cache and cookies on the new device, right? Could you share your app so I can try reproducing both versions?

Comment: I went back and looked at my cookies information. 1-dot-myapp.appspot.com only has a _ga cookie, the entry for myapp.appspot.com has 3 cookie values: application cache, ACID, and _ga. I was surprised that 1-dot-myapp.appspot.com did not have an application cache value in the cookie. So now I guess my question is. How can I force the application cache to renew as desired. I was under the impression that I could add a version to the manifest or do something along those lines to cause the cache to be updated upon deploy. This didn't seem to work for me. Any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back and looked at my cookies information. 1-dot-myapp.appspot.com only has a _ga cookie, the entry for myapp.appspot.com has 3 cookie values: application cache, ACID, and _ga. I was surprised that 1-dot-myapp.appspot.com did not have an application cache value in the cookie. So now I guess my question is. How can I force the application cache to renew as desired.

What I came up with was to either remove reference to my manifest file from my html or to rename my manifest file. So when ever I want to for the client browser to update the cache I redploy with a newly named manifest file. The manifst file is renamed with a version number like manifest2.mf. Then my build modifies all references for manifest to the newly name manifest file i.e. manifest2.mf. My html files and my appengine.xml file then us manifest2.mf . these changes seem to force the client browsers to update their cache.